# Altera nome do botão no evento

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estava fazendo um alteração no nome dos botões no projeto e acidentalmente cliquei duas vezes no botão, dai ele abriu o código, como não havia renomeado a variável abriu o código com o nome button7.

Como eu havia feito algumas alterações decidi salvar o projeto antes que algo mais de errado pudesse acontecer. Até ai tudo bem, sendo que depois fui la nas propriedades do botão para renomear e renomeei para btnSair só que no evento não mudou para btnSair continua como button7 no evento..

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda para fazer a alteração também no evento ?
Seria possível apenas renomear e refatorar?

Comment: Entre no evento do botão e faça o procedimento que o amigo @Christian Beregula passou abaixo. Para evitar novamente eventual transtorno utilize o botão direito selecionando o que quer renomear e selecione a  opção `Refactor` em seguida clique em `Rename` basta renomear para o nome desejado.

Answer (score 3):

É só ir na aba `eventos` do seu botão e achar o evento `click`, e colocar o nome que você deseja, e depois modificar o nome do evento em seu codigo para deixar igual.

Comment: botão direito selecionando o que quer renomear utilize a opção `Refactor` em seguida clique em `Rename` basta renomear para o nome desejado

Answer (score 2):

Se for este o seu caso, vc tbm pode simplesmente deletar o controle `button` e depois apagar o evento, antes, guarde o código para não ser deletado junto. Depois que fizer isso, crie novamente o controle `button` e agr renomeie-o para o que quiser e clique duas vezes.